# Select Last (first) rows of a table in Stored Procedure using parameter (SQL 2008)

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, parameters

I'm trying to create a stored procedure that uses

SELECT TOP 20 * from tblRecords ....

I want the number of rows returned to be sent to the procedure as a parameter.

For some reason it says I have a syntax error near the parameter I use:

SELECT TOP @PARAM from tblRecords ....

Is there a straight way to do it or will I need to construct the Statement using String concatenations and execute it....

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try :

```
SELECT TOP (@PARAM) * from tblRecords ....
```

MSDN recommends to use always parentheses, it's supported without for backward compatibility:

> [...For backward compatibility, TOP expression without parentheses in SELECT statements is supported, but we do not recommend this.](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189463.aspx)

Comment: Any idea what makes this different from regular use of parameters ?

Comment: I know, I have it in my code. I wonder why everywhere else I don't need to use () with @params....

Comment: Well, MSDN is not accurate as we can see that in select it doesn't work as well  - inside a SP.

Comment: 10x for the quick an enlightening response!

Answer (score 3):

In the stored procedure, before you do the select, issue a:

```
SET ROWCOUNT @param
```

That will limit the number of returned rows to @param.

After the query, set it back to 0:

```
SET ROWCOUNT 0
```

Comment: what happens if I doesn't reset it back to 0 ?

Comment: Queries will @param rows until you reset it.  Najmeddine's answer appears to work, that's definitely better.

Comment: This solution is also more backwards compatible with earlier versions of SQL that did not support the TOP((@Param) syntax

Comment: @JohnFX: I'd not worry about backwards compat nowadays... C'mon, it's 2009 with SQL 2008 R2